# How to check status of table in DynamoDB2?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, status

I am trying to move form `DynamoDB` to `DynamoDB2` to use tables with global secondary indices. I need to create a table and then batch-write items into it. Here's a block of tets code:

```
from boto.dynamodb2.fields import HashKey, RangeKey, GlobalAllIndex
from boto.dynamodb2.layer1 import DynamoDBConnection
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
from boto.dynamodb2.items import Item
import boto

conn = DynamoDBConnection(aws_access_key_id=<MYID>,aws_secret_access_key=<MYKEY>)
tables = conn.list_tables()

table_name = 'myTable001'
if table_name not in tables['TableNames']:
    Table.create(table_name, schema=[HashKey('firstKey')], throughput={'read': 5, 'write': 2}, global_indexes=[
        GlobalAllIndex('secondKeyIndex', parts=[HashKey('secondKey')], throughput={'read': 5, 'write': 3})], connection=conn)

table = Table(table_name, connection=conn)

with table.batch_write() as batch:
    batch.put_item(data={'firstKey': 'fk01', 'secondKey':'sk001', 'message': '{"firstKey":"fk01", "secondKey":"sk001", "comments": "fk01-sk001"}'})
    # ...
    batch.put_item(data={'firstKey': 'fk74', 'secondKey':'sk112', 'message': '{"firstKey":"fk74", "secondKey":"sk012", "comments": "fk74-sk012"}'})
```

When I run this code for the 1st time with a new value of `table_name`, I get the following error at the last line of the block:

```
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'Requested resource not found', u'__type': u'com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ResourceNotFoundException'}
```

When I run it one more time, it get executed fine. I suspect that the reason is simply that the table is still being created when I run it for the first time. How do I check for table's status in `DDB2`? In `DDB` I used `table.status` but this does not seem to be available in `DDB2`. What should I use instead?

**UPDATE**: Based on final response [**here**](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=146470#), the right way to extract table status is:

```
tdescr = conn.describe_table(tName)
print "%s" % ((tdescr['Table'])['TableStatus'])
```

Here are the other elements of the description dictionary:

```
for key in tdescr['Table'].keys():
    print key

GlobalSecondaryIndexes
AttributeDefinitions
ProvisionedThroughput
TableSizeBytes
TableName
TableStatus
KeySchema
ItemCount
CreationDateTime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conn.describe_table('table') to fetch the details about table & then check for the TableStatus field in the returned output.

Comment: Actually, I accepted the response too soon: the result of `conn.describe_table('table')` was a dictionary that did not have an `TableStatus` at all